# How can I get this jumping and movement code to work together?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use the Character Controller component in Unity and I managed to make the movement code, however, I was unable to add jumping and gravity or at least have them work together so my temporary solution was to just break them into 2 different methods. This probably isn't ideal so how could I get this to work properly?

```cs
void Update()
{
    GetInput();
    JumpingCode();
    MovementCode();
}

void JumpingCode()
{
    // Jumping
    if (jumpPressed && characterController.isGrounded)
        velocityY = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * (gravity * gravityScale));

    // Gravity
    velocityY += gravity * gravityScale * Time.deltaTime;   

    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, velocityY, verticalInput).normalized;   

    characterController.Move(direction * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void MovementCode()
{
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput).normalized;

    if (direction.magnitude > 0.1f)
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + playerCamera.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        Vector3 moveDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
        characterController.Move(moveDirection.normalized * walkSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand how you're arriving at the values you're using there, but the solution would be to accumulate the outputs and then do the .Move() action once at the end, like:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 motion;
    GetInput();
    motion += JumpingCode();
    motion += MovementCode();
    characterController.Move(motion*Time.deltaTime);
}
private Vector3 JumpingCode()
{
    // stuff
    return direction * walkSpeed;
}
private Vector3 MovementCode()
{
    // stuff
    return direction * walkSpeed;
}
```

Noteworthy there is that I dropped Time.deltaTime from your functions, but I don't know how you were using it in the code you provided.